# AVAudioPlayerDelegate method doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, delegation, xcode4.4

I'm simply trying to do something when an audio file has finished playing, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my .h file I've got this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@interface soundViewController : UIViewController
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    //various outlets
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end
```

And in the .m file I've got:

```
#import "soundViewController.h"
@interface soundViewController ()
@end

@implementation soundViewController
@synthesize audioPlayer;
```

And the method's:

```
- (void) playWord{
    Word *currentWord = [[Word alloc]init];
    currentWord = [testWords objectAtIndex:wordNum-1];
    NSString *item = [currentWord word];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], item]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
if (audioPlayer == nil){
    NSLog(@"error in audioPlayer");
    }
else{
    [audioPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"Playing word");
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    if (flag==YES){
        NSLog(@"Finished!");
    }
}
```

So... it all works swimmingly (apart from the fact that the sound file won't work if it starts with a capital letter), but why am I not seeing the log message "Finished" when the sound finishes?

Thanks for your help,
Morten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to set the delegate of the player after you instantiate it, like:

```
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Carl - thankyou so much. This fixed the problem. I inserted the code you suggested on the line immediately after the code beginning "audioPlayer = ...." and it now works perfectly!!! Thanks for taking your time to look at this.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome! Glad it helped. If you have a second please accept this answer to mark this question as resolved for other users. Thanks!

Comment: DONE :-) PS: I don't suppose you know how I can get the AVAudioPlayer to work with case sensitive audio file recognition?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you seeing works on sim/ not on device or vice versa issues?

Comment: Hi Carl. Yes - I have an audio file which speaks the word "I". If I name it "i.mp3" and retrieve it with the above code, it works on my iPhone and in the SIM. If I delete it in x-code, rename it "I.mp3" outside of x-code and import it again, it works in the SIM, but when it tries to play the word on the iPhone there is no sound, and I get an error message: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"! I really need capitalization of some specific files because of other considerations in the app... maybe I should start a new thread...

Comment: iOS is case sensitive in device so if you have a path with "i" in your program only file with lowercase i will work. So if you need to have files named with certain cases make sure your path construction matches. Probably make new thread though id

Comment: Sorry was typing that comment on my phone and kept messing it up, but yeah I'd say if that doesn't work open a new question.

Comment: Found the answer to this - even though in xcode the file shows as "I.mp3", and is also named "I.mp3" in the relevant resources folder (right click on file, and choose "Show in Finder"), in the actual bundle the file is still named "i.mp3", a remnant of earlier which isn't being updated with xcode changes. Can see bundle files by right clicking on the app name in the 'Products' folder, choose "Show in Finder", right click on Bundle, choose "Show Package Contents". Here you can check the actual files which are included in the app!!!